# If I enable local play, will it disable internet?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, networking

On my 3ds, if I am playing with someone locally, I don't see the internet. Does this mean I have disabled it?

Comment: I know that Animal Crossing only ever has one enabled at a time. Whether this is an issue with the hardware or software, however, I don't know.

Comment: It's anecdotal, but when playing Pokémon with some friends, I couldn't see those not on the internet when I was and vice versa. I'm guessing the 3DS uses a single antenna and some kind of ad-hoc network for local play and can't connect to both a normal wi-fi network and the local play network at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is anecdotal evidence, but when playing Pokémon with some friends, those using local play showed as offline while I was connected to the internet,

I suspect the 3DS uses a single antenna and some kind of ad-hoc network for local play. That would make it impossible to connect to both a normal wi-fi network and the local play network at once